# Window PopUp And Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I have a case where I have to validate if I click on upload button, window popup appears to select the file.

Can anyone please help me in doing this using robot framework.

Comment: You can use the Choose File keyword to upload a file. Verifying a popup for file selection is essentially testing the browser and not the web application.

Comment: To upload a file I am using choose file but I have to check for the windows popup. Can you please tell me how can I check this.

Answer (score 2):

If you only use a Windows interface, you can use AutoIt Library that provide keyword that can do what you need to do, here are the steps to install it:

- Install Pywin from this link https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20218/pywin32-218.win32-py2.7.exe/download
- Download the AutoIt Zipfile from here:
  https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/robotframework-autoitlibrary/AutoItLibrary-1.1.zip
- Install it as Library (If you don't know how, come back to me and i'll give you the steps)

Now you can use this keywords to upload your file:

wait for active window |WindowTitle="title of the upload window"
win active  | "title of the upload window" | Open
send    | "yourfile.extesion"
sleep | 1
control click   | "title of the upload window" | Open   | [CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]    | LEFT

Hope this helped you.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using Choose File. Here's a manual example of a File Upload that I had to do with Robot Framework.

1. Click *Add File* button on website.
2. Click *Upload File* button on website popup menu.
3. Click *[fileName]* on the OS GUI popup.
4. Click *Upload* on the OS GUI popup.
5. Click *Upload* on the website popup menu.
6. Click *Cancel* on the website popup menu.

Here's the code I used to do it.

```
Click Button    ${ADD_FILE}
Choose File     ${FILE_UPLOADS}     ${DEFAULT_FILE}
Click Button    ${UPLOAD_BUTTON}
Click Button    ${CANCEL_BUTTON}
```

Notice that Choose File saved me two steps, including going outside the DOM. A huge advantage of this is that you can run this in one window while your focus is on a different window.